# After I delete AutoComplete'option in FormItem, How could I clear input with the deleted value?

Tags: reactjs, antd

- Environment:
  Windows7/Chrome68.0.3440.84/React^16.2.0
- ant-design Version: 3.8.0
- **Link to minimal reproduction**:
  https://codepen.io/evanna51/pen/KBGEXb
- Happening: 
  After I deleted one option, the value still up to the input.
- Step to reproduce:

  1. click delete
  2. deleted `name1`.
  3. list no longer has `name1` but it still in input

I'm already deleted the option in state:`result.splice(key, 1);`,

and even use antD's form Method `setFieldsValue`,eg:`this.props.form.setFieldsValue({name: ""});`

How could I clear input after delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not possible using basic autocomplete of AntDesign, you need to use [Lookup-Patterns - Certain Category](https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/#components-auto-complete-demo-certain-category) method.

You can first define an `<OptGroup />` as:

```
const OptGroup = AutoComplete.OptGroup;
```

And then you may use `<OptGroup />` to mount over `<Option />` as given below:

```
const children = result.map((value, index) => {
  return (<OptGroup 
            key={index} 
            label={<Icon 
                     style={{'margin-top':'40px','float':'right','cursor':'pointer'}} 
                     type="close" 
                     onClick={this.deleteOption.bind(this, index)} />}>
            <Option key={index} value={value}>{value}</Option>
          </OptGroup>);
    });
```

I have updated the [live demo in CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBewZr?editors=0010).